# How to get ajax responses from fast to slow?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, axios, xmlhttprequest

1. requests send simultaneously
2. don't need to wait all response resolved

example: there are 3 request sending simultaneously

`axios.get(url1)` needs 1s to get response
`axios.get(url2)` needs 2s to get response
`axios.get(url3)` needs 3s to get response
how to get responses like res1 then res2 then res3 ?
promise.all and promise.race can not do this(because all will wait the lowest response not return from fastest to slowest, and race will return the fastest not all)

Comment: Don't use `Promise.anything`. Just use a `.then()` function for each call, and process its result when it comes.

Comment: thx@Barmar actually, I have an array that contains lots requests, it's difficult to add `.then()` for each one, and the requests are parallel

Comment: Are you doing the same thing with all the responses? If so, just do it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If all the URLs are in an array, you can simply loop over the array, calling `axios.get()` on each one.

```
urls.forEach(url => axios.get(url).then(response => { process the response }));
```

Comment: Does `forEach` send requests at the same time? It seems sending one by one

Comment: It should send them all simultaneously. But if they're going to the same server, browsers have a limit on the number of concurrent requests, I think 4.